# Center absolute positioned overflowing div

Tags: html, css

This is what I tried and it gets me 99% there.

```css
.polaroids-container {
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 245px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.polaroids {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container polaroids-container">
    <div class="polaroids">
      <div>Images here</div>
      <div>Images here</div>
      <div>Images here</div>
      <div>Images here</div>
      <div>Images here</div>
      <div>Images here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

This will center my content but the first element in the div is getting cut off on the left. As you can see in the image the scroll bar is all the way to the left so you cannot scroll left to see that content.

The objective here is to center all the divs within class `polaroids` and not have the first one not get chopped off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I did a quick fiddle and I see what you're doing now.  Add "left:0" to polaroids.  Once your alignment is set, then set your scroll to be centered using JavaScript.

```
.polaroids {
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  min-width: max-content;
}

<script>
  var polaroidsCont = document.getElementsByClassName("polaroids-container")[0];
  var polaroidsInner = document.getElementsByClassName("polaroids")[0];
  polaroidsCont.scrollLeft = (polaroidsInner.offsetWidth/2 - polaroidsCont.offsetWidth/2);
</script>
```

Comment: All that did was make the overflowing div no longer overflow the parent. I need this div to be scroll-able horizontally.

Comment: Did a quick test.  Looks like this is an alignment issue and not a margin issue like I first thought.  See revised answer.

Comment: left:0; completely removes the centering. I need the variable width absolute div to be centered. Even when its overflowing.

Comment: Try this.  The Left:0 fixes the cropping issue, but you then need to center your scrollbar using the above JavaScript.  What you were doing before was centering your content along the margin of your container which was cropping it.